# How do you include multiple activities in the Gradle Liquibase plugin's runList field?

Tags: testing, plugins, gradle, liquibase

I’m using Gradle 2.7 on Mac Yosemite with Java 8.  I’m using the Liquibase 1.1.1 plugin and would like to use it to do a couple of activities (build a test database and build my normal database).  So I have

```
liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
      File propsFile = new File("${project.rootDir}/src/main/resources/liquibase.properties")
      Properties properties = new Properties()
      properties.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
      changeLogFile 'src/main/resources/db.changelog-master.xml'
      url properties['url']
      username properties['username']
      password properties['password']
    }
    test {
        url 'jdbc:h2:file:target/testdb'
        username 'sa'
    }
    runList = (
        "test"
        "main"
    )
  }
}
```

But I can’t figure out the proper syntax for runList.  I get the error when running the above …

```
* Where:
Build file '/Users/myuser/Dropbox/cb_workspace/cbmyproject/build.gradle' line: 163

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/myuser/Dropbox/cb_workspace/cbmyproject/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/Users/myuser/Dropbox/cb_workspace/cbmyproject/build.gradle': 163: expecting ')', found 'main' @ line 163, column 2.
        "main"  
      ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to one of there example, the ***runList*** must be placed after the ***activity*** block:

```
liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
      File propsFile = new File("${project.rootDir}/src/main/resources/liquibase.properties")
      Properties properties = new Properties()
      properties.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
      changeLogFile 'src/main/resources/db.changelog-master.xml'
      url properties['url']
      username properties['username']
      password properties['password']
    }
    test {
        url 'jdbc:h2:file:target/testdb'
        username 'sa'
    }
  }

  runList = 'test, main'
}
```

See the example [here](https://github.com/stevesaliman/liquibase-workshop/blob/master/build.gradle).

Hope this helps.